# Listbox Binding Problem

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

Please solve my problem, my listbox don't bind, i don't why :(

```
class TLocation
{
    public string name;
}
```

Main Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TLocation}" x:Key="myTaskTemplate">
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Path=name, FallbackValue=name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListBox Height="131" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,44,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTaskTemplate}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Main Window Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<TLocation> list = new List<TLocation>();

        TLocation temp = new TLocation();

        temp.name = "hi";

        list.Add(temp);

        listBox1.ItemsSource = list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is a [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx), you can only bind to public [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) though. You might also want to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) if the name changes at runtime. If you are new to databinding make sure to read [the overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

e.g.

```
public class TLocation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name = null;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

*(Binding is also case senstitive and your capitalization is not following the [conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) so i changed it in my example, here the `Binding.Path` would need to be `Name`.)*

Comment: @ArMaN: Did you change the binding path to `Name`? Also: **[There are ways to debug bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)**, tell me the errors you get (and post them in future questions as well).